# How to convert a java swing application to work on android

Tags: java, android, swing

So I built a program in Java using swing for the interface and i didn't realize how difficult it would be to convert it to be used as an android application. Is there any way for me to easily convert or rebuilt the program to be sold in the android market place? If not can anyone point me toward any resources to help build a android.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did the same thing awhile back. Although there is no program out there that I know of to convert it directly. The Java code and the android code are very similar. Since android doesn't use swing's UI it uses `XML` based UI. once you get the UI functions of the android app down your Java code can be easily imported.

I am working on converting my Java app into an android app now. Most of my classes imported with no problem.

Comment: @Peter: XML UI Layouts at Android Developers: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 7):

AjaxSwing allows to convert Swing applications and use them directly on android or ipad, see http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/solutions/java_swing_ui_on_ipad.html

Comment: A free(er) alternative to this (Apache license) might be [webswing](http://webswing.org), ([git source on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/meszarv/webswing/commits/all)), though I haven't tried it and can't attest to how well it works.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is that I would build the UI in XML, then I give the items an ID and reference to it in Java, and then I'll trigger everything by button clicks so what one button does in your swing layout does the same on android. You can't copy/paste it.

Answer (score 1):

swing UI was meant for desktops and pc's but for 
android you have to use Xml then you can keep your java codes as they are in the various activities 
then use your event handling skills to trigger them

Answer (score -11):

- Open the project's properties
- Select Java Build Path
- Select Libraries tab

From there you can Add External Jars and you can use swing layout

Comment: Swing does not work on Android, so adding the libs will not make any difference...