# Questions regarding Windows/Android development (Java:APK/JAR)

Tags: java, android, windows, apk

I'm planning to write a software (with GUI and sounds) that should run under Android and Windows 7/8

I guess the best approach for this is to use Java?
I am new to Android and Java development so my questions are:

-So can I use one development platform to create both (APK & JAR), namely Java?
-As far as I understand for Android I need to compile (from same source?) a .APK file and for Windows a .JAR file ?
(The .JAR will run in the Java Runtime that is installed in Windows)
-If I use Java what would be the best IDE, something like Google's Android Studio (will it allow to create .JAR?) or Oracle's JDK (Java SE Development Kit) ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to write an app that will run on both OS's, since all GUI components are part of different frameworks (Android SDK for Android, SWT/Swing/... on Windows), and not compatible with all OS's.

You best bet is probably a web-based app. You can run it in the browser on dektop and either on a mobile browser on Android, or package it as a fullscreen `WebView` running your web app. The best part is it would also work on iOS.

You could also write your app for desktop in Swing and then convert it to an Android app, you can find questions on StackOverflow on the subject, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206120/how-to-convert-a-java-swing-application-to-work-on-android).

Hope this helps ;)