# Java to Android Conversion

Tags: java, android

I have seen a few things on this website about converting java code to android. However, I do not want to re write my code unless absolutely necessary. I have always wanted to release a game to the google play store, and have been working hard to do so in the past couple of weeks. I decided to code the game in java, thinking that I could convert it to work on the Android operating system when finished. However, I am now at the point where I am ready to convert the game, and I am having lots of trouble. My game requires java's "paintComponent" and Graphicsd2D. ***My question: is there any possible way to use java's Graphics in android?*** I use lots of things with this class, such as resizing images

Comment: "is there any possible way to use java's Graphics in android" -- not really.

Comment: @CommonsWare what path do you suggest that I take?

Comment: Rewrite the UI component completely in Android.  If your code was written with good separation of UI from logic then the logic parts should port over with no to minimum changes.

Comment: Android is using a different graphics API than Swing for UI rendering.  You have to make it run on Android API, by using Android dev tools like Android Studio together with the Android SDK. The Equivalent for Graphics2D would be https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html
Start with any Android Canvas tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a java swing application to work on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206120/how-to-convert-a-java-swing-application-to-work-on-android)

Comment: For games in particular, you may be interested in finding an existing game engine that works on the platforms that you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **No direct way to convert Java (Swing/AWT) GUI into Android GUI**. Since Java GUI is heavier for mobile applicaiton.
However you just start converting your java GUI components into Android XML view one by one. That is the only way.

If working on Web Application, You can use this [WebSwing](http://webswing.org/). It will allows to run any swing application inside your web browser using only pure HTML5. It is Open Source.