# Does Eclipse for Android developers is not compactable with Java projects ? It shows Null Pointer exceptions

Tags: java, android

Code****************************************************************************

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JSlider;

//import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;

public class Main{// extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            JFrame w = new JFrame();
            w.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
            JSlider slider = new JSlider();
            slider.setMinimum(1023);
            w.add(slider);
            w.pack();
            w.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error***************************************************************************

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206120/how-to-convert-a-java-swing-application-to-work-on-android

Comment: I'm going to flag as "Unclear what you're asking". Are you trying to get JFrame working on Android, or are you just trying to use Eclipse to make a standard Java application using JFrame? Either way, Eclipse support for Android [was dropped a long time ago](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

Comment: My question is : I need to develop a java application . But I already have a version of Eclipse that I used to develop Android applications. So do I need to download an Eclipse that indented only for Java or can I use the older one ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.there is no JFrame in Android.

Comment: But this has nothing todo with Eclipse. It depends on the JDK and libs which is used.

Comment: How can I update my JDK ? Jest download and Install it or any change in settings of Eclipse ?

Comment: that's neither an answer, nor it follows the question. Either delete that, or put it as a comment below the question; after all - we can all express our opinions right..

Comment: there is no JFrame in Android,not JDK