# Java-Bytecode to .dex or .apk dont work... What's to do?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, dex

I am testing to write a Javaprogramm in Eclipse (IDE).
My Target is, that it will work on Windows, Linux and Android.

To export it as .class or .jar ist no problem!
I managed to convert it with the Android-Studio-Tool "dx" too convert the .jar as .dex and .apk too (god, that was a terrible process)

When I try too run them on my android phone (v6.0.1) only the .apk is executable... and when I run the .apk i got:

"Parsingfehler - Beim Parsen des Pakets ist ein Fehler aufgetreten" 
(Parsingerror - At the parsing of the packet an error occured)

what did i do wrong? i post my code, perhaps there is an error:

```
/** v0.01 vom 22.06.2017 @author Rudolf Geist */
package allgemeines;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Systemausleser 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Ich will eine Main, die überall läuft
        System.out.println("Infos auslesen \n");

        System.out.println("Zeichen zwischen Ordnern (Betriebssystem-Abhängig!) : " + System.getProperty("file.separator") );
        System.out.println("OS-Name: " + System.getProperty("os.name") );
        System.out.println("OS-Architektur (OS-Bit-Version): " + System.getProperty("os.arch") );
        System.out.println("User Name: " + System.getProperty("user.name") );

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Es klappt!");
    }

}
```

As I tried to start the .class or .jar of this programm [called it "testi"] with an .bat [Windows] or an sh. [Linux - Lubuntu] it worked!

Can I continue to develop only on blank Eclipse and try after that to convert to an android compatible format... or should I rething my process?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Java *Swing* library; this [doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206120/how-to-convert-a-java-swing-application-to-work-on-android) on Android.

Where *Swing* deals with `JFrame`s and `JPanels`, Android uses things like `Activity`s and `FrameLayout`s. This means Android just won't know how to execute your code, since it has no idea what a `JOptionPane` even is.

You should try only migrating basic computation, and avoid any operating-system specific calls. You can verify which functions are supported by checking your package calls against the [Android API](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html), or quickly pasting your code into [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to see if makes any complaints.

If you do need a platform-independent UI, you should look towards native integrations with an available library such as [`nanovg`](https://github.com/memononen/nanovg), or search for a platform-agnostic solution. I created [`ribbon-vg`](https://github.com/Cawfree/Android-RibbonVG-Example) for this exact issue.

Comment: if I understand your answer right, it means the whole GUI-handling is different. So the background logic should be compatible. In my case all the sysout-Lines should work, or are thy os-specific too?

I copied the part in androd studio, but with the outcommented two lines it didn't work again (after I converted this new .jar again).

I tried to comment the both lines with java.swing out...

Did i miss something?

Comment: You're absolutely right. `System.out.println()` is supported by Android, it'll come up in Logcat output using the tag `System.out`. Have you tried compiling your code as a `.jar` and including it in the Android build path?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean with build path.
Yes I have Eclipse (Compiler set on v1.7) and Android Studio.

For now I exported it as jar (Testi.jar).

Next I opended CMD, swiched to the HDD with ":d", navigated to the folder of android studio "cd D:\AndroidStudioSDK\build-tools\25.0.3" and than started the dx-tool: dx --dex --output="[path]\testi.apk" "[path]\testi.jar"   I moved this  created .apk (testi.apk) via usb-cable to my androidphone... when i try to start it over my handy tochpad... I got the error massage... do you see my error or how I can let it work?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO your approach is wrong for Android. You can not create a `main` method that runs everywhere, especially as Android is not a common Java environment.

From my perspective the more helpful approach would be to develop a system independent library that then can be used by system dependent applications.

Therefore you could provide three different applications:

- One console based/head-less Java application
- One Swing based Java application
- One Android based application

Comment: ok from the comments from the bottom answer I understanded it. I am now testing tu write my code at the top only with sysouts... but this wont work on my android too... same error. what did i do wrong?

Comment: Have you created a real Android app with AndroidManifest.xml (binary encoded), a correct dex file, a Java-Manifest and signed?

Comment: no I havn't. I wrote the above .java file in Eclipse (no extensions!). I installed the android studio and tried to convert the compiled .class with the dx tool to an .apk.
This wont't start.

What should I do?

Comment: Use Android Studio and/or Gradle and create a complete Android App that includes your code. Otherwise your code will never be executed. Android is not Java, for example there is no `main` function.