# Package java.awt doesn't exist on android studio but working on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, awt

I have written a simple graphic application in Java, using awt and swing, with Eclipse and it works. Now i wanted to use the same application in android, then i installed android studio but when I try to copy 'n' paste the code I get the error "package java.awt doesn't exist". I googled the error and some are saying it is a configuration/setting up problem and some that it isn't, however none of them seems to have a solution. I'm new in Java, probably it is a stupid problem.

Comment: You can't run swing applications directly on android. See [How to convert a java swing application to work on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206120/how-to-convert-a-java-swing-application-to-work-on-android)

Comment: Thanks a lot, then what i should do is looking for a graphic library that works on android and that is as similiar as possible to swing?

Comment: Yes, but I'll be surprised if you find one that's similar. You're probably better off biting the bullet and learning a new UI library.

Comment: Oh ok... thank you, do you have any suggestions?